# Sending API JSON data to Exasol DB table

Tags: python, json, exasol

I am working with fake JSON data from a dummy JSON site that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  }
]
```

I read in the API data through the `requests` library then turn around and send it into an Exasol DB table. See code below

```
import requests
import pyexasol

def get_api_data():
    r = requests.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
    data = r.json()
    return data
    
def connection():
    session = pyexasol.connect_local_config('my_exasol')
    return session

def send_api_data():
    s = connection()
    data = get_api_data()
    for row in data:
        s.execute("""INSERT INTO TESTBED.TEST_API(postId, id, name, email, body) VALUES ({postId}, {id},{name},
        {email}, {body})""", {'postId': row['postId'], 'id': row['id'], 'name': row['name'], 'email': row['email'],
        'body': row['body']})

send_api_data()
```

This works fine, the problem is it is incredibly slow.  It takes almost 2 mins to insert 500 records.  I know there must be a more efficient way to do this.  In reality I will be pulling in data from an API that has thousands of records that I will want to turn around and send into a DB table.

Any ideas on a better approach to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing single insert statements is slow in Exasol, because it's a column based database. You should use [IMPORT](https://docs.exasol.com/sql/import.htm) instead. Make sure to read the [best practices](https://github.com/badoo/pyexasol/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md#avoid-using-insert-prepared-statement-to-import-raw-values-in-sql) for pyexasol as well. Also consider enabling [compression](https://github.com/badoo/pyexasol/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md#enable-compression-for-wifi-connections).

For your example, try the following. It takes 0.7 seconds to import the data in my case.

```py
import requests
import pyexasol
import pandas
import time

def get_api_data():
    r = requests.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
    data = r.json()
    return data
    
def connection():
    session = pyexasol.connect_local_config('my_exasol')
    return session

def send_api_data():
    s = connection()
    data = get_api_data()

    data_for_import = [(row['postId'], row['id'], row['name'], row['email'], row['body']) for row in data]
    start = time.time()
    s.import_from_iterable(data_for_import, ("TESTBED","TEST_API"))
    print("Finished import after ", time.time() - start, " seconds")

send_api_data()
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you!  In my case it took about 3.5 seconds but I think that is because I am going through VPN to a DB that resides on a server.  Still, 3.5 seconds is way better than 2 minutes :)

Comment: Great to hear that it worked for you! Did you [enable compression](https://github.com/badoo/pyexasol/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md#enable-compression-for-wifi-connections)? That might improve the speed even more.

Comment: good call, thanks. I will add that as well